# Unused Property WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I find the unused property warning super useful in a lot of situations, but often I get an error in the following situation:

```
const hello = () => 'Hello world!';

module.exports = {
  hello, // <-- saying this is unused
};
```

I see that you can turn this feature off, but I'd rather keep it.

Comment: it's not marked unused if you import it in a different file, like `const { hello } = require("./hello")`

Comment: I see, I'm new to WebStorm so I didn't realize how smart it actually was! you should answer the question so I can give you a ✅

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export is marked unused if the exported module is not imported anywhere.
To get rid of the issue, you need importing the module in a different file, like:

```
 const { hello } = require("./hello")
```

Comment: One thing I'm realizing is that if import the entire file elsewhere like:

    `const Query = require('./resolvers/Query');`

and use it like this it's still giving me that error...